# Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | BN'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, buffer, ethereum

I have a Typescript project. Within that project is the following function:

```
import { hexToBytes, toHex } from 'web3-utils'

const signMessage = (msg: Hash) => {
    //  msg is a keccak-256 hash
    //
    const hashed = Buffer.from(hexToBytes(msg))
    const prvKey = Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, "hex")
    const { signature, recid } = ecdsaSign(hashed, prvKey)
    // add key recovery parameter
    const ethSignature = new Uint8Array(65)
    ethSignature.set(signature)
    ethSignature[64] = recid
    return toHex(Buffer.from(ethSignature))
  }
```

This is taken from [here](https://github.com/urbit/urbit/blob/roller/typescript-client/pkg/npm/roller-api/tests/roller.test.ts#L82). In that context, the function works fine. However, VSCode semantic highlighting marks the final line of the function as an error and provides the following:

```
const ethSignature: Uint8Array
Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | BN'.
  Type 'Buffer' is missing the following properties from type 'BN': clone, toNumber, toArray, toArrayLike, and 81 more.ts(2345)
```

What is going on here, and how do I resolve this?